# wilcox.test on negative values in R

Tags: r, testing

In R I have 2 data.frames `data1` and `data2` where `length(data1)=83` and `length(data2)=1300`, similar we have `head(data1)`

```
[1]  -347.85  -210.00    10.00  -348.96  -349.50  -349.36   -80.00  1051.70
 [9]  -348.50  -348.51  -350.00  -349.70  -350.00   750.32  -216.30  -348.80
```

and `head(data2)` is

```
[1] -299.36    0.00 -580.68  -81.80    0.00 -100.00
```

I calculate the mean `mean(data1)=-281` and `mean(data2)=-1285`. From looking the mean of `data2`  is much lower than `data1`.

```
median(data1)=-348.5
```

and `median(data2)= -299.75`

And `summary(data1)` gives

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-4547.0  -349.9  -348.5  -281.0  -156.7  1892.0
```

and `summary(data2)` gives

```
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-59280.0   -799.8   -299.8  -1285.0   -100.0  56920.0
```

In R I use `wilcox.test` to see if `data1` is stat. sign. to `data2`

I type

```
wilcox.test(data1,data2)
```

and get p-value 0.18, ie they are stat. sign. equal

```
When I type wilcox.test(data1,data2,alternative="greater")
```

I get p-value 0.09 and for

```
wilcox.test(data1,data2,alternative="less")
```

I get p-value 0.9.

All this I find very strange. How can all 3 p-values be above 0.05?
Since there is such a huge difference in the two mean-values I expected a low p-value (a difference in between `data1` and `data2`). 
How can that be?

Comment: mean value is sensitive to estremely large / small values. Check their medians. I would look at the distribuiton of data1 and data2 first.

Comment: In addition of showing `head(data)` include the `median(data)`, a summary or even boxplots of the data. This should explain why you see a insignificance.

Comment: The Wilcoxon Rank Sum test is effectively testing the hypothesis that P(X < Y) = 0.5.  It does not translate to a test regarding differences of means, nor of medians.  What you've shown is that there isn't reason to believe that P(X < Y) is different from 0.5, nor is it less than 0.5, nor is it greater that 0.5.  My conclusion here would be "X is not typically less than Y."

Comment: First, I think this question 
fits better Cross Validated. Second you’re example is not reproducible; you should provide a workable example. Third, one thing I can think of is that the variance  is too high  $$(\frac {N_{r}(N_{r}+1)(2N_{r}+1)}{6}})$$  Or is this a truism answer